# How to sort an Instant with only day in springframework.data.domain.sort

Tags: java, sorting, spring-data-jpa

I need sort some column in database with condition: Sort by date first, if two days are a same day then sort by others... The column date in my database is Instant type (I use MySQL).

I use method Sort of springframework to implement:

```
Sort.by(Sort.Order.asc("date"), Sort.Order.asc("abc"),...);
```

The problem is when two days are a same day but different hour (Example: 2020-09-29 01:56:06.887142 and 2020-09-29 13:24:02.211884), it still sort the date (order by hours, and minutes, seconds).

How could I sort the day only with method Sort of springframework.data.domain and Instant type ?

Comment: How about `Sort.TypedSort.by(Function<T,S>)`?

Comment: @SSC I don't get it, could you more explain or some code for the example ?

Comment: sort is more on loading all result and the doing inmemory sorting, where as orderby is more efficient if result set is more

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an alternative way with using native query to call datetime function of SQL as below:

```
@Query(value = "select * from `2wp_user` u order by DATE(u.created_date)",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<User> findAllUserCustom();
```